# Can you get someone's IP address using Skype?

Tags: ip, skype

If you're chatting with them via Skype, how can you get their IP address?

Do you need some kind of program or is there a simple, obvious way?

Is it illegal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, I am not sure if this is illegal or not as this will most likely be dependent on your location.

I personally use the following site to gain the IP Address of a Skype Contact. Go to http://resolveme.org/ and enter the Skype ID of the contact you want the IP Address of.

Comment: hmm, i just tried it and it gives me an error.  does the person need to be connected at the time?

Comment: @thisisjnd As far as I was aware they do need to be logged in. Have you tried using it on yourself when you're logged into Skype to see if it returns your IP Address?

Comment: hmmm, I tested it on myself and it gave me my ip address both times.  Connected and disconnected.  Maybe it was because I tried it first while I was connected and it....logged it?  somehow?

Comment: Not sure tbh, I've never had an issue with either someone being online of offline. Is it possible for that other person to be online again or would it be trying to find out the IP from a historical conversation only?

Comment: they'll be online again.  ill check then and get back to you.  thanks for your help though!

Comment: resolveme.org is down

Answer (score 5):

I have Skype running on a computer, and I can see that the Skype client is periodically exchanging packets with my contacts on Skype. So it is possible to figure out the IP address of your contacts simply by looking on network traffic on your own computer.

I am not aware of any jurisdiction in which it is illegal to look at what is happening on your own computer.

The above method may fail to work if both of you are connected to the Internet through a NAT device. If you want to be sure the packets exchanged with your contacts are going directly, then run the Skype client on a computer with a public  IP address.

You will find the Skype client communicating with many different IP addresses, so figuring out which IP corresponds to which contact may require you to correlate periods where they are online with periods where a specific IP is showing up. Otherwise one would have to know a little bit about what is going on inside the Skype client itself.

Comment: Skype clients will also be communicating with supernodes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_protocol#Peer-to-peer_architecture) which are Microsoft controlled servers. Thus, not every IP detected will be one of the client's contacts.